# Unity based washing/ cleaning game advice

Tags: unity, spine

I'm thinking about a way I can create a washing/ cleaning game as part of a project I'm working on within Unity, but given my lack of experience, I'm having trouble knowing where to start.

The goal is to be able to apply an effect of some kind to a Spine based character - which has a default 'idle' animation, and have the touch/ mouse positions remove the parts of the effect according to those positions.

I'm unsure how to go about creating such an effect - would I need to create a 'dirty' version of each sprite image used within the Spine imported character and make parts of it transparent, or would something like a shader be suitable?

While I have a lot of experience with C#, I have little experience with Unity, and having Googled for examples or tutorials or creating something like this, I'm left no better off...

I was hoping for some advice or pointers from the community...

Thanks!
Kieron

Comment: I'm not quite clear (pun intended) on what you mean with a washing/cleaning game. I've previously answered [programmatically changing attachment transparency in Spine](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/66674/7804) and [detecting how much of an object has been "cleaned" by a player](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/70386/7804) which might be relevant here. Could you describe some more the effect you want to achieve, and perhaps show something you've tried?